# how to access second field in django choice field in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

In my django models i have a charfield status which is filled by choices

```
status = [
    ('Accepted','Accepted'),
    ('Pending','Acceptance Pending'),
    # ('Document_Pending','Document Pending'),
    ('Rejected','Rejected'),
    ('Pending_email_verification','Pending Email Verification'),
    ('pending_document','Document Pending'),
    ('pending_document_verification','Cerificate Verification Pending'),

]
```

in my template i want to print cerificate verfication pending but it always print pending_document_verfication which is expected because in the data it is stored but how can i print Certificate Verfication Pending

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [get_FOO_display() - [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) where FOO is the name of the field.

```
{{ obj.get_status_display }}
```

Comment: jinja2 version: {{ obj.get_status_display() }}